# Cannot call "persistInt" from inner class within Preference class

Tags: android, android-preferences

i'm trying to work with building my own `Preference` classes, and having a bit of trouble.  it looks like the way of saving data to a preference is via the "persist" group of methods within the `Preference` class.  however, in my preference, i open a color picker dialog, and i need to save the preference from within the dialog's `colorChanged` override.  whenever i run the app and try to change the color preference, i get:

```
06-05 10:21:46.396: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(516): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method android.preference.Preference.persistInt:(IIII)V from class android.preference.ColorSelectionPreference$1
at android.preference.ColorSelectionPreference$1.colorChanged(ColorSelectionPreference.java:55)
at android.apis.graphics.ColorPickerDialog.onClick(ColorPickerDialog.java:168)
```

(UPDATE: 6/5/12 12:20) i tried using `callChangeListener` to force the `onPreferenceChangeListener` to trigger, but it crashes with an identical error.  without `callChangeListener`, the preference data is (probably) saved, but the `onPreferenceChangeListener` doesn't get triggered:

```
06-05 12:20:23.691: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2834): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method android.preference.ColorSelectionPreference.callChangeListener:(IIII)V from class android.preference.ColorSelectionPreference$1
at android.preference.ColorSelectionPreference$1.colorChanged(ColorSelectionPreference.java:52)
at android.apis.graphics.ColorPickerDialog.onClick(ColorPickerDialog.java:168)
```

here's the actual class:

```
package android.preference;

import android.apis.graphics.ColorPickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class ColorSelectionPreference extends Preference {
    private Context mContext;
    private int mColor;

    public ColorSelectionPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public ColorSelectionPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return mColor;
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        mColor = color;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        //get original preference
        //set ColorPickerDialog to original preference color or default color
        ColorPickerDialog dialog = new ColorPickerDialog(mContext, new ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener() {
            public void colorChanged(int a, int r, int g, int b) {
                int selectedColor = Color.argb(a,r,g,b);
                setColor(selectedColor);

                /*** crashes on callChangeListener ***/
                //SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
                //SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                //edit.putInt(getKey(), selectedColor);
                //edit.commit();
                //callChangeListener(selectedColor);

                /*** the offending code, error refers to this line ***/
                persistInt(selectedColor);

                /*** tried this as well by request on IRC ***/
                //ColorSelectionPreference.this.persistInt(selectedColor);
            }
        }, mColor);
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You tried `ColorSelectionPreference.this.persistInt(selectedColor);`.  I might suggest trying `ColorSelectionPreference.persistInt(selectedColor);`.  This looks like a problem I had earlier.  I can't be sure without loading it up in Eclipse.

Comment: persistInt isn't a static method.

Comment: for now i have to work around this by setting a `Handler` to the `Preference` class and calling back to the `PreferenceActivity` when a change is registered.  however, this is really hacky and i'd rather do it the right way if anyone knows how.

Comment: I added a better answer if you're curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a hacky workaround that uses a Handler to call back to the main class from the inner class.  it isn't pretty, but it works.

```
package android.preference;

import android.apis.graphics.ColorPickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class ColorSelectionPreference extends Preference {
    private Context mContext;
    private int mColor;

    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if(msg.getData().containsKey("color")) {
                int color = msg.getData().getInt("color");
                setColor(color);
            }
        }
    };

    public ColorSelectionPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public ColorSelectionPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return mColor;
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        mColor = color;
        persistInt(new Integer(color));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        //get original preference
        //set ColorPickerDialog to original preference color or default color
        ColorPickerDialog dialog = new ColorPickerDialog(mContext, new ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener() {
            public void colorChanged(int a, int r, int g, int b) {
                int selectedColor = Color.argb(a,r,g,b);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("color", selectedColor);
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.setData(bundle);
                mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

                //setColor(selectedColor);

                /*** tried this, but the onPreferenceChangedListener never gets triggered, so this won't work ***/
                //SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
                //SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                //edit.putInt(getKey(), selectedColor);
                //edit.commit();
                //callChangeListener(selectedColor);

                /*** the offending code, error refers to this line ***/
                //container.

                /*** tried this as well by request on IRC ***/
                //ColorSelectionPreference.this.persistInt(selectedColor);
            }
        }, mColor);
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem myself.  I do not pretend to understand it, but this seems like an easier fix:

```
// ...why is this necessary?  what is special about Preference.persistInt?
@Override protected boolean persistInt(int value)
{
    return super.persistInt(value);
}
```